# How to set null foreign key with entity framework 4.3.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity

I'm in trouble when I remove a gallery of a post by setting although I'm sometimes accepts null null when I perform debugging, but retreat when the break point, it is not the null value how can I solve this problem?
este  codigo :

```
 var postold = _postRepositorio.ObterPorId(postDto.Id);

        if (postold.ImagemCapa != postDto.ImagemCapa && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(postDto.ImagemCapa) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(postold.ImagemCapa))
        {
            if (
                File.Exists(
                    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(
                        Path.Combine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DiretorioImagem"], postDto.ImagemCapa))))
            {
                File.Delete(
                    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(
                        Path.Combine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DiretorioImagem"], postold.ImagemCapa)));
            }
        }
        var editPost = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(postDto, postold);
        editPost.CategoriaPost = _categoriaPostRepositorio.ObterPorId(postDto.CategoriaPost);

        editPost.Galeria = postDto.Galeria == 0 ? null : _galeriaRepositorio.ObterPorId(postold.Id);

        _postRepositorio.Editar(editPost);

        _contexto.SaveChanges();
```

Here's where I put null for the gallery

```
 editPost.Galeria = postDto.Galeria == 0? null: _galeriaRepositorio.ObterPorId (postold.Id);
```

Comment: This is very unclear. "although I'm sometimes accepts null", "but retreat when the break point". What exactly is the problem?

Comment: the problem is that the foreign key does not accept null value

Comment: Sure does not and how best but it was a way I found to do that receive foreign key null value `do { editPost.Galeria = null; } while (editPost.Galeria != null);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here has to do with the fact that EF will lazy load navigation properties by default, unless you explicitly eager load them using `.Include()`.

With lazy loading, a navigation property will be `null` until you try to access it for the first time. During that first access, EF will hit the db to load the data into the navigation property.

Your code is not doing that. You are trying to set it to null before the property is lazy loaded. You could try this instead:

```
var tenerGaleria = editPost.Galeria == null; // this will trigger the lazy load
if (postDto.Galeria == 0 && tenerGaleria)
    editPost.Galeria = null; // now setting it to null should work
else if (postDto.Galeria != 0)
  editPost.Galeria = _galeriaRepositorio.ObterPorId(postold.Id);
```

If your entity also exposed a foreign key, you could just set it to null without worrying about the lazy / eager loading of the navigation property.

```
if (postDto.Galeria == 0)
    editPost.GaleriaId = null; // set the FK to null
else
    editPost = _galeriaRepositorio.ObterPorId(postold.Id);
```